# It is showing that unexpected end of input as error, what should i do

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
 const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/User')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    // Create a new user
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body)
        const status = 1
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.status(201).send({status, user, token })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})

router.post('/users/login', async(req, res) => {
    //Login a registered user
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password)
        const status = 1
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({error: 'Login failed! Check authentication credentials'})
        }
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({ status,user,token })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }

})

router.get('/users/me', auth, async(req, res) => {
    // View logged in user profile
    res.send(req.user)
})

router.post('/users/me/logout', auth, async (req, res) => {
    // Log user out of the application
    try {
        req.user.tokens = req.user.tokens.filter((token) => {
            return token.token != req.token
        })
        await req.user.save()
        res.send()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
})

router.post('/users/me/logoutall', auth, async(req, res) => {
    // Log user out of all devices
    try {
        req.user.tokens.splice(0, req.user.tokens.length)
        await req.user.save()
        res.send()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }
})
router.patch('/users/places/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
const allowedUpdates = ['places']
const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

if (!isValidOperation) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid updates!' })
}

try {
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id})

    if (!task) {
        return res.status(404).send()
    }
    else{

    updates.forEach((update) => {
      task[update] = update === 'places' 
        ? task[update].map(places=>places.place === req.body[update].place ? req.body[update] : places)
        : req.body[update]
    })
    updates.forEach((update) => {
        task[update] = update === 'places' 
          ? task[update].map(places=>places.latitude === req.body[update].latitude ? req.body[update] : places)
          : req.body[update]
      })
      updates.forEach((update) => {
        task[update] = update === 'places' 
          ? task[update].map(places=>places.longitude === req.body[update].longitude ? req.body[update] : places)
          : req.body[update]
      })
    }
    await task.save()
    res.send(task)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e)
})



module.exports = router
```

```
It is showing an error at line no 102
Unexpected end of input as error and I am not able to understand the error as I am new to the code in nodejs.
below given is the log of the yarn run v1.22.4
4:23:43 PM web.1 |  $ env-cmd -f ./.env node src/app.js
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  H:\Minor\Backend\src\ro
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  uters\user.js:106
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  module.exports = router
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  .js:1044:19)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Minor\Backend\src\app.js:3:20)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  error Command failed with exit code 1.
4:23:44 PM web.1 |  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
4:23:44 PM web.1 Exited with exit code nullterminal showing the error
```

the above given is the log of the code running in a terminal
And the error is Unexpected token')'
Please help me in resolving this error 
as I am new to node js so I don't know much about it and on google also I am not able to find any solution................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... Please review my code once and help me in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

It forgot

```
})
```

before `module.exports = router`

Put your code inside it, https://beautifier.io/ and look...

Update:

Yep, look at the last try catch :

```
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }) // <--- remove the )
})
```

Comment: After adding the above brackets, it is showing unexpected token error               })
5:14:18 PM web.1 |   ^
5:14:18 PM web.1 |  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Comment: Look at your code, indent it, and check the parenthesis... Didn't you have a lighter on your ide ? If you're using a blocnote to code, I can suggest you to use any kind of free code editor, that will highlight to code and you will be abble to show directly this kind of errors. I think it's the main problem